# Robellini Palm oozing Brown oil

Tags: plant-health, palm

My Robellini palm (*Phoenix roebelenii*) has while dots on leaves and brown oil all over leaves and the ground surrounding tree. I’ve tried to upload a picture but it’s not working

Comment: Really need a closeup picture of the leaves to determine if it's scale or bacteria

Comment: Try to fix uploading, it may be that your pic is too large, or of unsupported format. Without picture, you can't really get a good answer.

Comment: Ok I’m going to try to get picture to upload

Comment: Welcome Lois Lane! If you continue to have trouble uploading a picture, let us know what error message you're getting and we should be able to help you! You can also post a link to it if you can upload it someplace else, and we can adjust it and download it from there. Our system can be tricky!